# ajax data - replacing html vs updating value attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

An app I am working on has a 50 row x 100 col grid, where each cell is a div containing 1 textbox, with one outer div containing the entire grid to handle scrolling. Exact dimensions can vary, but that it a typical max size. So, that works out to about 5000 divs, each with its own textbox, for a total of 10,000 elements.

The contents of the grid need to be updated via ajax calls to load data for different periods.

My question is, which of these 2 approaches would be more efficient:

1) Have the ajax call return the full formatted HTML for the grid, and simply set the innerHtml of the containing div to the new contents.

2) Have ajax cal return JSON or similar, then use javascript/jquery to loop through and update the values of each grid cell in the existing divs. Might need to add or delete a few columns in this case, but number of rows will remain constant.

For smaller grids/tables, returning the complete html works great, and requires very little client JS code, but I have heard about performance issues when manipulating large numbers of DOM elements. With the huge number of attributes and properties associated with each element, I can see where it could add up to a lot of overhead to create/destroy 1000s of them. So, I thought I would ask for advise here before deciding which way to go on this. Thanks.

Comment: option 2 is best so the data stays separate from all the mark up.. this way if the HTML markup changes your data is still intact without adding all the changes to the DOM, versus replacing everything.. you could do a speedtest with debugging tools in the browser inspector to benchmark each method - http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/innerhtml/ -

Comment: I would go with option 2, but additionally I would create the mechanism to  update only this portion of the table which is visible to the user asynchonously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been through the very same situation.  For tables of a certain size and complexity, it is much faster to render pregenerated HTML over and over again than to hunt for and update the data, but you wind up with a server communication lag to contend with.

The key here is "manipulate".  If you're just painting the grid, it's not very costly in terms of time unless there are a lot of events that fire on complete, like event bindings and so forth.  Even those aren't too bad.  At some point, there is a diminishing return and single cell updates becomes more tolerable.

It really depends on what the users do with the grid.  If they are updating many rows / cells, you might want a bulk update function for applying changes to multiple selected rows at once so they don't have to wait for each individual cell change to refresh.  This was our solution for large tables as individual cell updates when making lots of changes were too time consuming and reloading the whole table from the server was not too bad if you're only doing it once per batch of updates.